# How do I get the result into a variable MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have the following PHP script. How do I get the correct results. Each query should only return a number. I need to get `rank` in this case. I was also wondering how to combine those two queries into one statement.

```
function getRankings($country, $deviceid)
{

$queryWorld = "SELECT 1 + (SELECT count( * ) FROM ScoreTable a WHERE a.score > b.score ) AS rank FROM
ScoreTable b WHERE DeviceID='$deviceid' ORDER BY rank LIMIT 1";

$queryCountry = "SELECT 1 + (SELECT count( * ) FROM ScoreTable a WHERE a.score > b.score  AND Country='$country') AS rank FROM ScoreTable b WHERE DeviceID='$deviceid' ORDER BY rank LIMIT 1";

$resultWorld =  mysql_query($queryWorld) or die(mysql_error());  
$rowWorld = mysql_fetch_row($resultWorld);
$resultCountry =  mysql_query($queryCountry) or die(mysql_error());
$rowCountry = mysql_fetch_row($resultCountry);

$arr = array();
$arr[] = array("WorldRanking" => $rowWorld[0], "CountryRanking" => $rowCountry[0]);
echo json_encode($arr);         
}
```

If I type the queries individually into MYSQl I get the correct answers. But the `echo` produces

```
[{"WorldRanking":null,"CountryRanking":null}]
```

It should be something like

```
[{"WorldRanking":"4","CountryRanking":"1"}]
```

I think I need to get the value of  `rank` but I do not know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
function getRankings($country, $deviceid)
{

$queryWorld = "SELECT 1 + (SELECT count( * ) FROM ScoreTable a WHERE a.score > b.score ) AS rank FROM
ScoreTable b WHERE DeviceID=$deviceid ORDER BY rank LIMIT 1";

$queryCountry = "SELECT 1 + (SELECT count( * ) FROM ScoreTable a WHERE a.score > b.score  AND Country='$country') AS rank FROM ScoreTable b WHERE DeviceID=$deviceid ORDER BY rank LIMIT 1";

$resultWorld =  mysql_query($queryWorld) or die(mysql_error());  
$no_of_results_in_resultWorld = mysql_num_rows($resultWorld);
if($no_of_results_in_resultWorld > 0){
    $rowWorld = mysql_fetch_row($resultWorld);
}

$resultCountry =  mysql_query($queryCountry) or die(mysql_error());
$no_of_results_in_resultCountry = mysql_num_rows($resultCountry);
if($no_of_results_in_resultCountry > 0){
    $rowCountry = mysql_fetch_row($resultCountry);
}

$arr = array();
$arr[] = array("WorldRanking" => $rowWorld[0], "CountryRanking" => $rowCountry[0]);
echo json_encode($arr);         
}
```

check whether it is returning results or not.

Comment: This seems to produce the result I wanted `[{"WorldRanking":"4","CountryRanking":"1"}]` will select it as the answer if further check confirm it.

Answer (score 1):

try your code like this, but I don't know this code correct or not:

```
function getRankings($country, $deviceid)
{

$queryWorld = "SELECT 1 + (SELECT count( * ) FROM ScoreTable a WHERE a.score > b.score ) AS rank FROM
ScoreTable b WHERE DeviceID='$deviceid' ORDER BY rank LIMIT 1";

$queryCountry = "SELECT 1 + (SELECT count( * ) FROM ScoreTable a WHERE a.score > b.score  AND Country='$country') AS rank FROM ScoreTable b WHERE DeviceID='$deviceid' ORDER BY rank LIMIT 1";

$resultWorld =  mysql_query($queryWorld) or die(mysql_error());  
while ($rowWorld = mysql_fetch_row($resultWorld)){
$value1 = $rowWorld['filedname1'];
}
$resultCountry =  mysql_query($queryCountry) or die(mysql_error());
while($rowCountry = mysql_fetch_row($resultCountry)){
$value2 = $rowWorld['filedname2'];
}

$arr[] = array("WorldRanking" => $value1, "CountryRanking" => $value2);
print_r($arr);        
}
```

Comment: If each query only produces 1 result, can I avoid the `while` loop? Also what `filename1` and `filename2` should be?

Comment: I think this should be research by your self. I am not clear about it. Anyway, my code can show what you want?

Comment: I tried it. But still produce null result unfortunately.

Comment: FYI, your code is wrong because you are using $row[0] and you do not specific which field you want to select.

Comment: I know it's not correct. The reason for $row[0] is because I thought it should only contains one row. Should the field be `rank` than? I tried that but does not work also.

Comment: By the way I think there's is no field, because the rank is created during runtime and not part of the table.

Comment: you try to echo both $row inside the loop. see whether there display any result or not